# Cosine similarity return empty

Tags: python, redis, embedding, redis-py

I am trying to access the most similar vectors but it returns empty and I don't understand.

I am following this documentation: https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/search_vector_similarity_examples.html

And this is my schema:

```
schema = (
                TagField("ticket_url"),
                NumericField("ticket_id"),
                NumericField("entity_id"),
                VectorField("embedding",
                            "HNSW", {
                                "TYPE": "FLOAT32",
                                "DIM": self.vector_dim,
                                "DISTANCE_METRIC": "COSINE",
                            }
                            ),
            )
            definition = IndexDefinition(
                prefix=[self.doc_prefix], index_type=IndexType.HASH)
            self.r.ft(self.index_name).create_index(
                fields=schema, definition=definition)
```

The function to search similar vectors

```
def search_similar_documents(self, entity_id, vector, topK=5, ticket_id=None):
        query = (
            Query("*=>[KNN 2 @embedding $vec as score]")
            .sort_by("score")
            .return_fields("score")
            .paging(0, 2)
            .dialect(2)
        )

        query_params = {"vec": vector}
        return self.r.ft(self.index_name).search(query, query_params).docs
```

[image]

Vectors are generated from an openai response and converted to bytes

```
def embedding_openai(self, text):
        try:
            response = openai.Embedding.create(
                input=text,
                model="text-embedding-ada-002"
            )
            embedding = response['data'][0]['embedding']
            array_embedding = np.array(embedding, dtype=np.float32)
            return array_embedding.tobytes()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            return None
```

And redis.ft(index).info() return this

```
{'index_name': 'conversations', 'index_options': [], 'index_definition': [b'key_type', b'HASH', b'prefixes', [b'tickets:'], b'default_score', b'1'], 'attributes': [[b'identifier', b'ticket_url', b'attribute', b'ticket_url', b'type', b'TAG', b'SEPARATOR', b','], [b'identifier', b'ticket_id', b'attribute', b'ticket_id', b'type', b'NUMERIC'], [b'identifier', b'entity_id', b'attribute', b'entity_id', b'type', b'NUMERIC'], [b'identifier', b'embedding', b'attribute', b'embedding', b'type', b'VECTOR']], 'num_docs': '973', 'max_doc_id': '973', 'num_terms': '0', 'num_records': '3892', 'inverted_sz_mb': '0.00634765625', 'vector_index_sz_mb': '6.00555419921875', 'total_inverted_index_blocks': '2999', 'offset_vectors_sz_mb': '0', 'doc_table_size_mb': '0.086483001708984375', 'sortable_values_size_mb': '0', 'key_table_size_mb': '0.030145645141601562', 'records_per_doc_avg': '4', 'bytes_per_record_avg': '1.7101746797561646', 'offsets_per_term_avg': '0', 'offset_bits_per_record_avg': '-nan', 'hash_indexing_failures': '0', 'total_indexing_time': '347.62900000000002', 'indexing': '0', 'percent_indexed': '1', 'number_of_uses': 1, 'gc_stats': [b'bytes_collected', b'0', b'total_ms_run', b'0', b'total_cycles', b'0', b'average_cycle_time_ms', b'-nan', b'last_run_time_ms', b'0', b'gc_numeric_trees_missed', b'0', b'gc_blocks_denied', b'0'], 'cursor_stats': [b'global_idle', 0, b'global_total', 0, b'index_capacity', 128, b'index_total', 0], 'dialect_stats': [b'dialect_1', 0, b'dialect_2', 0, b'dialect_3', 0]}
```

the vectors are stored as bytes, I don't know if it's the algorithm or I'm the problem :/

Comment: How do you generate your vectors? Can you add an example?

Comment: Most likely there is a problem with your indexing. Can you see if there are “indexing failure” in `FT.INFO` output?

Comment: @A.Guy I edited with the info requested

Comment: Hmm. 0 indexing failure suggests that the index is fine, and if you don’t get an error when searching it’s probably also fine. Try running with timeout 0 (so there is no time limit) and see if that’s your problem

Comment: Who should have the timeuot? :O

Comment: I deleted the index and created again and it works xD

Comment: You can pass `.timeout(0)` to the query object. But it’s probably not it if a rebuild fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Was this resolved? A few things it could be

If you have alot of documents and you're using the FLAT index, it could be that the search simply isn't returning in the alloted 500ms timeout. This can be configured on startup or just use HNSW.

https://redisvl.com has a few examples of this in the user guide.